# Firebase Messaging crashes in foreground

Tags: android, ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

I am developing a Flutter app with `Firebase Messaging` and `Awesome Notifications` (https://pub.dev/packages/awesome_notifications). Below is my code.

```
import 'dart:developer' as developer;

import 'package:awesome_notifications/awesome_notifications.dart';
import 'package:firebase_core/firebase_core.dart';
import 'package:firebase_messaging/firebase_messaging.dart';

void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();

  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  FirebaseMessaging _messaging = FirebaseMessaging.instance;

  FirebaseMessaging.onBackgroundMessage(_firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler);

  //Request permission for firebase messaging

  NotificationSettings settings = await _messaging.requestPermission(
    alert: true,
    announcement: false,
    badge: true,
    carPlay: false,
    criticalAlert: false,
    provisional: false,
    sound: true,
  );

  if (settings.authorizationStatus == AuthorizationStatus.authorized) {
    print('User granted permission');

    FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen((RemoteMessage message) async {
      RemoteNotification? notification = message.notification;
      AndroidNotification? android = message.notification?.android;
      print("REMOTE MESSAGE LISTENER");
      if (message.data["data_type"] == "TEXT") {
        await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
              id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
              groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              title: message.data["name"],
              body: message.data["body"],
              summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
              displayOnBackground: true,
              displayOnForeground: true),
        );
      } else if (message.data["data_type"] == "IMAGE") {
        await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
          content: NotificationContent(
              id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
              groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
              channelKey: 'basic_channel',
              title: message.data["name"],
              body: Emojis.art_framed_picture + " " + message.data["body"],
              summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
              notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
              displayOnBackground: true,
              displayOnForeground: true),
        );
      }
    });
  } else {
    print('User declined or has not accepted permission');
  }

  /// Update the iOS foreground notification presentation options to allow
  /// heads up notifications.
  await FirebaseMessaging.instance.setForegroundNotificationPresentationOptions(
    alert: true,
    badge: true,
    sound: true,
  );

  FirebaseMessaging.instance.getInitialMessage().then((RemoteMessage? message) {
    developer.log("REMOTE MESSAGE");
    if (message != null) {
      developer.log(message.data.toString());
    }
  });

  // For handling notification when the app is in background
  // but not terminated
  FirebaseMessaging.onMessageOpenedApp.listen((RemoteMessage message) {
    print("onMessageOpenedApp executed");
  });

  AwesomeNotifications().initialize('resource://drawable/logo', [
    NotificationChannel(
        channelGroupKey: 'basic_tests',
        channelKey: 'basic_channel',
        channelName: 'Basic notifications',
        channelDescription: 'Notification channel for basic tests',
        defaultColor: Color(0xFF9D50DD),
        ledColor: Colors.white,
        importance: NotificationImportance.High),
  ]);

  runApp( child: MyApp());
}

// Declared as global, outside of any class
Future<void> _firebaseMessagingBackgroundHandler(RemoteMessage message) async {
  // If you're going to use other Firebase services in the background, such as Firestore,
  // make sure you call `initializeApp` before using other Firebase services.
  await Firebase.initializeApp();
  developer.log("background listener called");
  print("Handling a background message: ${message.data}");

  // Use this method to automatically convert the push data, in case you gonna use our data standard
  //AwesomeNotifications().createNotificationFromJsonData(message.data);
  if (message.data['data_type'].toString().toUpperCase() == "TEXT") {
    print("Handling a background message: ${message.data['data_type']}");
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
          groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          title: message.data["name"],
          body: message.data["body"],
          summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
          displayOnForeground: true,
          displayOnBackground: true),
    );
  } else if (message.data['data_type'].toString().toUpperCase() == "IMAGE") {
    await AwesomeNotifications().createNotification(
      content: NotificationContent(
          id: UniqueKey().hashCode,
          groupKey: message.data["senderUid"],
          channelKey: 'basic_channel',
          title: message.data["name"],
          body: Emojis.art_framed_picture + " " + message.data["body"],
          summary: message.data["body"], // Anything you want here
          notificationLayout: NotificationLayout.Messaging,
          displayOnBackground: true,
          displayOnForeground: true),
    );
  }
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    AwesomeNotifications()
        .actionStream
        .listen((ReceivedNotification receivedNotification) {
      developer.log("Notification clicked");
      developer.log(receivedNotification.body ?? "no data");
    });

    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home: LoadingScreen()); // LoginLanguageSelectScreen());
  }
}
```

Below is my **AppDelegate**

```
import UIKit
import Flutter
import GoogleMaps

@UIApplicationMain
@objc class AppDelegate: FlutterAppDelegate {
  override func application(
    _ application: UIApplication,
    didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]?
  ) -> Bool {
      if #available(iOS 10.0, *) {
        UNUserNotificationCenter.current().delegate = self as? UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate
      }
      application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
      GMSServices.provideAPIKey("xxxx-xxxx")
    GeneratedPluginRegistrant.register(with: self)
    return super.application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
  }
}
```

My code is working fine in Android and iOS. However when it comes to executing notifications in **foreground**, the app crashes with the following error. This happens `only in iOS`.

```
* thread #1, queue = 'com.apple.main-thread', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0x16f793ff8)
    frame #0: 0x0000000188cfd7dc libswiftCore.dylib`swift_conformsToProtocolMaybeInstantiateSuperclasses(swift::TargetMetadata<swift::InProcess> const*, swift::TargetProtocolDescriptor<swift::InProcess> const*, bool) + 44
libswiftCore.dylib`swift_conformsToProtocolMaybeInstantiateSuperclasses:
->  0x188cfd7dc <+44>: str    w2, [sp, #0x68]
    0x188cfd7e0 <+48>: strb   w2, [sp, #0x77]
    0x188cfd7e4 <+52>: adrp   x22, 445806
    0x188cfd7e8 <+56>: ldr    x8, [x22, #0x5a0]
Target 0: (Runner) stopped.
```

This happens in `FirebaseMessaging.onMessage.listen` lietener. If I remove the `Awesome Notifications` code from there, it works fine.

What is the issue here and how to fix it?

Comment: Check that message.data contains the keys you are using.

Comment: @user18309290: Not sure what you meant?